# Zero Accuracy in Sentiment Analysis FFNN Model (Pytorch)

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I'm constructing a feedforward neural net (FFNN) for binary sentiment classification using movie review dataset. It's a simplified task with only two class labels, i.e., positive (1) and negative (0). It FFNN makes word embeddings, averages them, runs them through two layers and activation later, and then applies a sigmoid too get a probability for prediction.

The model runs, but I keep getting zeroes. I am in desperate need of help.
[Here's the link to the colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1nbK_G7snlw0Jxtxzv5ro_qPOHBvDnsfV?usp=sharing)

I tried the following:

- Changing the loss function
- Rearranging the model order
- Changing the embedding dimensions

## Below is the following:

1. The model
2. The assignment of the FFNN
3. The training

### Here's the code:

#### ***THE MODEL***

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

import torch
from typing import List

import torch.nn as nn

class FeedForwardNeuralNetClassifier(nn.Module):
    """
    The Feed-Forward Neural Net sentiment classifier.
    """
    def __init__(self, vocab_size, emb_dim, n_hidden_units):
        """
        In the __init__ function, you will define modules in FFNN.
        :param vocab_size: size of vocabulary
        :param emb_dim: dimension of the embedding vectors
        :param n_hidden_units: dimension of the hidden units
        """
        super(FeedForwardNeuralNetClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.vocab_size = vocab_size
        self.emb_dim = emb_dim
        self.n_hidden_units = n_hidden_units
       
        # TODO: implement a randomly initialized word embedding matrix using nn.Embedding
        # It should have a size of (vocab_size x emb_dim)
        self.word_embeddings = nn.Embedding(self.vocab_size, self.emb_dim) # replace me

        # Define the rest of the model
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(self.emb_dim, self.n_hidden_units)
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(self.n_hidden_units, 1)
        self.activation = nn.ReLU()
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, batch_inputs: torch.Tensor, batch_lengths: torch.Tensor) -> torch.Tensor:
        """
        The forward function, which defines how FFNN should work when given a batch of inputs and their actual sent lengths (i.e., before PAD)
        :param batch_inputs: a torch.Tensor object of size (n_examples, max_sent_length_in_this_batch), which is the *indexed* inputs
        :param batch_lengths: a torch.Tensor object of size (n_examples), which describes the actual sentence length of each example (i.e., before PAD)
        :return the logits of FFNN (i.e., the unnormalized hidden units before sigmoid) of shape (n_examples)
        """

        # Lookup word embeddings
        embeddings = self.word_embeddings(batch_inputs)

        # Element-wise averaging layer
        averaged = torch.mean(embeddings, dim=1)

        # Hidden layer ReLU
        hidden = self.activation(self.layer1(averaged))

        # Output layer
        return self.layer2(hidden)

        

    def batch_predict(self, batch_inputs: torch.Tensor, batch_lengths: torch.Tensor) -> List[int]:
        """
        Make predictions for a batch of inputs. This function may directly invoke forward (which passes the input through FFNN and returns the output logits)

        :param batch_inputs: a torch.Tensor object of size (n_examples, max_sent_length_in_this_batch), which is the *indexed* inputs
        :param batch_lengths: a torch.Tensor object of size (n_examples), which describes the actual sentence length of each example (i.e., before PAD)
        :return: a list of predicted classes for this batch of data, either 0 for negative class or 1 for positive class
        """
        output = self.forward(batch_inputs, batch_lengths)
         
        # Sigmoid
        probability = self.sigmoid(output)

        # Convert logits to predicted labels
        predicted_labels = (probability > 0.5).int().tolist()

        return predicted_labels
```

#### **THE ASSIGNMENT**

```py
model = FeedForwardNeuralNetClassifier(vocab_size=len(vocab), emb_dim=300, n_hidden_units=300)

# FeedForwardNeuralNetClassifier(
# (word_embeddings): Embedding(4818, 300)
# (layer1): Linear(in_features=300, out_features=300, bias=True)
# (layer2): Linear(in_features=300, out_features=1, bias=True)
#  (activation): ReLU()
#  (sigmoid): Sigmoid()
# )



device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
print(device)
model = model.to(device)



optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.001) # replace me
```

#### **THE TRAINING**

```py
import time

BATCH_SIZE=32
N_EPOCHS=20

# create a batch iterator for the training data
batch_iterator = SentimentExampleBatchIterator(
    train_exs, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, PAD_idx=PAD_IDX, shuffle=True)

#loss function
loss_func = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()

# training
best_epoch = -1
best_acc = -1
start_time = time.time()
for epoch in range(N_EPOCHS):
    print("Epoch %i" % epoch)

    batch_iterator.refresh() # initiate a new iterator for this epoch

    model.train() # turn on the "training mode"
    batch_loss = 0.0
    batch_example_count = 0
    batch_data = batch_iterator.get_next_batch()
    while batch_data is not None:
        batch_inputs, batch_lengths, batch_labels = batch_data
        # project to the device
        batch_inputs = batch_inputs.to(device)
        batch_lengths = batch_lengths.to(device)
        batch_labels = batch_labels.unsqueeze(1)
        batch_labels = batch_labels.to(device)
        

        
        # TODO: clean up the gradients for this batch
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        # TODO: call the model and get the loss
        outputs = model(batch_inputs, batch_lengths).float()
        
        batch_labels = batch_labels.float()
        loss = loss_func(outputs, batch_labels)
        # record the loss and number of examples, so we could report some stats
        batch_example_count += len(batch_labels)
        batch_loss += loss.item() * len(batch_labels)

        # TODO: backpropagation using loss
        # backpropagation using loss
        loss.backward()

        # update the model parameters
        optimizer.step()

        # get another batch
        batch_data = batch_iterator.get_next_batch()

    print("Avg loss: %.5f" % (batch_loss / batch_example_count))

    # evaluate on dev set
    model.eval() # turn on the "evaluation mode"
    acc, _, _, _ = evaluate(model, dev_exs, return_metrics=True)
    if acc > best_acc:
        best_acc = acc
        best_epoch = epoch
        print("Secure a new best accuracy %.3f in epoch %d!" % (best_acc, best_epoch))
        
        # Save the current best model parameters
        print("Save the best model checkpoint as best_model.ckpt!")
        torch.save(model.state_dict(), "best_model.ckpt")
    
    print("Time elapsed: %s" % time.strftime("%Hh%Mm%Ss", time.gmtime(time.time()-start_time)))
    print("-" * 10)

print("End of training! The best accuracy %.3f was obtained in epoch %d." % (best_acc, best_epoch))

# Load back the best checkpoint on dev set
model.load_state_dict(torch.load("best_model.ckpt"))
```

Comment: We do not take colab links for code, all (relevant) code must be in the question as text.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy All done! I made sure to be verbose!

Comment: When computing accuracy, you have to threshold probabilities at 0.5 to obtain classes (0/1), which then you can compare to your ground truth labels. What you currently do is compare probability to 0/1 class and that never works.

Comment: where do I do that int he code? I thought I did that in my predict function or is that wrong

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Snoopy! You were absolutely right; I posted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> ##### *Thank you @Dr.Snoopy for your insight!*

---

### The Solution

The issue was a lack of understanding how to utilize the probabilities once I get them from `nn.Sigmoid()` in `batch_predict`. When working on binary classification, it's typical to, rather than what I did:

```py
# Sigmoid
probability = self.sigmoid(output)

# Convert logits to predicted labels
predicted_labels = (probability > 0.5).int().tolist() #WRONG
```

...to create your mask via:

```py
# Convert logits to predicted labels
  predicted_labels = (probability > 0.25) #CORRECT
```